# Stop all postgres services

Tags: cmd, windows-services, pipe

I'm trying to write a cmd that will stop all instances of PostgreSQL on my server

`net start | find /I "postgres"`

returns all my running instance

I thought this would work

`net start | find /I "postgres" | net stop`

no luck
I also looked at

`for /F "delims=" %A in ('net start | find /I "postgres"') do echo %A`

There must be some way to do this

Comment: As far as I know the `cmd` does not provide text trimming function, right? I tried PowerShell with `net start | ? { $_.Contains("Apache")} | % { net stop $_.Trim() }` and works (with UAC of course). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't know of a simple way to trim in cmd. Your method worked. I have not spent any time on power shell yet and I guess now is a good time to start. Would you mind unpacking that a bit? I'm good with the .NET syntax it's the ? and % and $_ i'm not sure about.

Comment: Ooo, sorry since I'm really lazy to type even some characters at some time (and even my teacher-used-to-be blamed me a bit about this).
`?` is alias of `Where-Object`, whilst `%` is alias of `ForEach-Object`, and the `$_` is to mention piped element. In this case, every element from traversing array by `ForEach-Object` is piped into inner expression.

Comment: These aliases and commands are available for a help text by `Get-Help {func}` or `man {func}`.

Comment: Thanks for getting me on track and finally motivating me to learn powershell. If you post your answer I'll mark it as such.

Any favorite power shell resources?   I like http://ss64.com/ps/

Comment: And I thank you for supporting me!

Comment: I was learning PS from that site too and some of posts from this site only, more than enough at least to submit assignments to my institute course orz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the cmd does not provide text trimming function, right? I tried PowerShell with

```
net start | ? { $_.Contains("postgres")} | % { net stop $_.Trim() }
```

and works (with UAC of course).

To explain,

- `?` is alias of Where-Object, whilst
- `%` is alias of ForEach-Object, and
- `$_` is to mention piped element. 
  In this case, every element from traversing array by `ForEach-Object`(`%`) is piped into inner expression.

*These aliases and commands are available for a help text by `Get-Help {func}` or `man {func}`.*

Comment: in PS how would you run this:

Runas /profile /user:postgres "robocopy C:\temp\pgsql \"C:\Program files\PostgreSQL\9.5\" /e"
I can't escape it correctly. I could convert it all to dospath but there must be a way to escpe " correctly for runas.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't escaped properly. With necessary changes to run on my machine it showed the command line you intended. What does windows say your problem is rather than your guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic service where name='lanmanserver' call stopservice
```

does lanmanserver, adjust to your program.

```
wmic /?
wmic service get /?
wmic service call /?
```

Or same objects in vbscript.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Service")

For Each objItem in colItems
    'msgbox objItem.caption 
    If LCase(objItem.name) = "lanmanserver" then msgbox objItem.stopservice
Next
```